# Progam Stopped while the condition running

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Silahkan Isi Jumlah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }
```

the specific code

```
btnharga.setOnClickListener {
            if (spinner.selectedItem.toString().equals("Ukuran")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Silahkan Isi Ukuran", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else if (spinner.selectedItem.toString().equals("44")){
                if (spinner2.selectedItem.toString().equals("Jenis Laminasi")){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Silahkan Isi Laminasi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else if (spinner2.selectedItem.toString().equals("Glossy")){
                    val total : Int
                    val totall : String
                    val value = editText.getText().toString()
                    val finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value)
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Silahkan Isi Jumlah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }
                    else if (finalValue < 5){
                        total = finalValue * 3500
                        totall = total.toString()
                        editText2.setText(totall)
                        spinner.isEnabled = false
                        spinner2.isEnabled = false
                        editText.isEnabled = false
                        editText2.isEnabled = false
                    }
```

why my application force closed when this program is run ??

The erorr Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.inisiator.com, PID: 4717
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at app.inisiator.com.RequestPinActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(RequestPinActivity.kt:83)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: Is this code inside a onClickListener, Add more code in your post.

Comment: You should add the error log from Logcat to make the question cleaner

Comment: Can anyone tell me what return@setOnClickListener does??

Comment: @PembaTamang It's just a `return` to skip commands below (only commands inside   `setOnClickListener`)

Comment: `val finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value)` - because `value` is empty.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it is number

Comment: where is 'RequestPinActivity.kt:83'

Comment: the exception says that it is empty. Are you sure that you are using right EditText?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens because you are trying to parse a string (empty string) which is not able to parse to an integer.

Move `Integer.parseInt` command to below checking text empty

And remember to catch NumberFormatException when parsing number from text

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Silahkan Isi Jumlah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return@setOnClickListener
}

try {
   val finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value)
   if (finalValue < 5){
       total = finalValue * 3500
       totall = total.toString()
       editText2.setText(totall)
       spinner.isEnabled = false
       spinner2.isEnabled = false
       editText.isEnabled = false
       editText2.isEnabled = false
   } 
} catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
    //Add log for parsing error of do something else
}
```

Comment: the problem at the if, if value is empty, the toast not show and the program force closed

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You parse empty string to integer so that's why its throw the exception

The following is correct:

```
String a = 50;
int number = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

And this is an error because empty string cannot be converted to integer:

```
String a = "";
int number = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

In your code:

```
val finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

change this line check if the values is empty or not before parsing and then parse only if it isn't empty

Comment: i still confused, can you give me more specific example ?

Comment: first check whether the string value is empty or not then parse the value , i.e if the string value is empty we are not able to parse that to string value

Answer (score 0):

Your code has this logic:

```
val finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value)
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
    ...
} else if (finalValue < 5){
    ...
}
```

So, if `value` is an empty string, which you obviously expect that it can be, `parseInt` will throw that `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` exception.

You need to check for empty string *before* trying to call `parseInt`.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
    ...
} else {
    val finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value)
    if (finalValue < 5){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is causing `NumberFormatException`-

```
val value = editText.getText().toString()
val finalValue = Integer.parseInt(value)        //here value is "" empty
```

empty string or invalid string can't be converted to Int.

So use a if condition before parsing string to int -

```
if(!value.isNullOrEmpty()){
//parse here
}
```

or use try/catch with `NumberFormatException`